# Output By Month With Only One Header

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

I've been trying to take this from my current output to a 'by month' output. I'm about to pull all of my hair out on this one. What I'm trying to do is group the games in months. So `January, feb march` ect would have each games underneath it. Right now I have to do this for every team and create a static `placeholder` and new variables for each.

DATABASE STRUCTURE

```
[id]   [opponent]   [month]   [team]   [notes]   [date_added]   [buyLink]
[time]   [date]

<?php
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
// Connect to the `MySQL` database
include "../../includes/db_conx.php"; 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$sqlcountRam = "SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE team='cyoram' ORDER BY date ASC";
$sql_countRam = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqlcountRam);
$calCountRam = mysqli_num_rows($sql_countRam); 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($calCountRam > 0) {
// get all the product details

 $x=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_countRam)){


             $id = $row["id"];
             $opponent = $row["opponent"];
             $team = $row["team"];
             $notes = $row["notes"]; 
             $month = $row["month"];

             $buyLink = $row["buyLink"];

             $time = $row["time"];
             $date = $row["date"];
             $formatted_date = date("l d F Y H:i A", strtotime($date));
             $raw = "$formatted_date";
             $xplod = explode(' ',$raw);
/*\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\*/
include "includes/logos.php"; 


/*\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\*/
 $classCssRam = "inline-block";
  $x++; 
$classChangeRam = ($x%2 == 0)? 'whiteBackground': 'grayBackground';

 $product_listRam .= "  
   <div class='aNew' style='clear:both;display:<?php echo $classCssRam; ?>'>

<div class='monthSalute'>$month</div>

    <table width='400px' border='0'>
                <tr class='$classChange'>
                    <td rowspan='2' class='date' >$xplod[1]</td>
                    <td class='day'>$xplod[0]</td>
                 <td rowspan='2' class='centerLogo'><div class='containImgPos'><img src='$imgLogo' height='32px' style='position:relative;left:$posImgR;' /></div></td>
                    <td class='city'>$city</td>
                    <td rowspan='2' class='butt_pad'><a href='calendar_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='calendar_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='$classChangeRam'>
                    <td class='time $classChangeRam'>$time</td>
                    <td class='opponent $classChangeRam'>$opponent</td>
              </tr>
    </table>
</div>



";
    }
    }
 else {
    $product_listRam = "";
    $classCssRam = "none";
}

?>
```

Comment: Please provide DB Schema with few data...

Comment: Date is the actual date. Sorry I forgot to add that Sudheesh. I included it in the original post.

Comment: For each row, check whether `$month` is the same as the previous row. Only output the `monthSalute` DIV when the month changes.

Comment: Why do you have both `month` and `date` columns? Can't you just get the month from the date?

Comment: @Barmar this was the method I used prior to display the month. This can be ignored. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the above answer. I'm a little confused as to what you mean. Can you expand on this with an example of what you mean.

Comment: @Barmar to clarify what I understand & what I mean. I know you mean output only the inner divs if the last row month is the same else echo full. What I'm confused by is how to check the last row as well as how to check by month.

Answer (score 1):

make change to date format in database structure and include startdate and end date to fetch data according to months like this : this will give u the data month wise, hope its usefull

```
 $mon = 1;
 $i=1;
                    $specify = array();
                    while($mon <=12)
                    {
                        $startdate = '2012-'.$mon.'-01';
                        $enddate = '2012-'.$mon.'-31';`
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discounts   WHERE `date` BETWEEN '".$startdate."' AND '".$enddate ."'");
$row[i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the use of `$monthDiv` in the code below.

I also fixed a mistake. You can't use `<?php echo ... ?>` inside a string, you should just interpolate the variable.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_countRam)){


    $id = $row["id"];
    $opponent = $row["opponent"];
    $team = $row["team"];
    $notes = $row["notes"]; 
    $month = $row["month"];

    $buyLink = $row["buyLink"];

    $time = $row["time"];
    $date = $row["date"];
    $formatted_date = date("l d F Y H:i A", strtotime($date));
    $raw = "$formatted_date";
    $xplod = explode(' ',$raw);
    /* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ */
    include "includes/logos.php"; 

    /* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ */
    $classCssRam = "inline-block";
    $x++; 
    $classChangeRam = ($x%2 == 0)? 'whiteBackground': 'grayBackground';

    /* Print month heading for new month */
    if ($last_month != $month) {
        $monthDiv = "<div class='monthSalute'>$month</div>";
        $last_month = $month;
    } else {
        $monthDiv = "";
    }

    $product_listRam .= "  
   <div class='aNew' style='clear:both;display:$classCssRam;'>

   $monthDiv

    <table width='400px' border='0'>
                <tr class='$classChange'>
                    <td rowspan='2' class='date' >$xplod[1]</td>
                    <td class='day'>$xplod[0]</td>
                 <td rowspan='2' class='centerLogo'><div class='containImgPos'><img src='$imgLogo' height='32px' style='position:relative;left:$posImgR;' /></div></td>
                    <td class='city'>$city</td>
                    <td rowspan='2' class='butt_pad'><a href='calendar_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='calendar_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='$classChangeRam'>
                    <td class='time $classChangeRam'>$time</td>
                    <td class='opponent $classChangeRam'>$opponent</td>
              </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been trying to debug this without having to post again, but I can't seem to get it. Right now it looks like the last month days of the month are getting thrown around. I've got for example December and a list of games then January and a list of games. The last game for January has its own heading for some reason though. Any idea on why this may occur. I checked the entry in the database and it has the correct month.

Comment: So for example I've got :

[[January -- Header]]
Jan 03 
Jan 24
Jan 25
[[January -- Header]]
Jan 26
Jan 29